# Implementing DFA minmization algorithm with JAVA ArrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, dfa

I have implemented the [DFA minimization algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization) with array lists, but it doesn't return the correct answer. If someone could point out which part of the algorithm I am missing, I would appreciate it.(And correction on whether I have used an efficient way to implement it).

The program is supposed to read data from a file and then work on it. But this function has nothing to do with those data. I have hard coded it to work.

The method that implements the algorithm is named (unreachableStates)

DEBUG I: So I went thorough the code, and found out that the problem is the loop that surround the expression | temp.add(transitionTable[j][i]) |. This will work for the first 2 iterations, but after that it will not consider all the states. Now the challenge is to fix it.

[image]

```
package dRegAut;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class dfamin {
    // Global variables to hold data from the file
    private int numStates,numAlphabets,numFinalStates;
    private char alphabets[];
    private boolean finalStates[];
    private int [][] transitionTable;

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws Numberfor matException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Numberfor matException, IOException {
        int numStates,numAlphabets,numFinalStates;
        char alphabets[];
        boolean finalStates[];
        int [][] transitionTable;

        // Take file name and open a stream to read it
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("/path/to/file/trace");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileStream));

        // Store each line from the file
        String line;

        // Read each line from file
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            // Read single spaced data from each line
            String [] splittedLine = line.split(" ");

            // Read numStates,numAlphabets from the line
            numStates = Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[0]);
            numAlphabets = Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[1]);
            //for (int a=0;a<numAlphabets;a++){
            //alphabets[a] = '0';
            //}
            transitionTable = new int[numStates][numAlphabets];
            int tt= 2;

            // Loop thorough the line and read transition table
            for (int row=0;row<numStates;row++){

                for (int col=0;col<numAlphabets;col++){
                    transitionTable[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[tt]);

                    tt++;

                } // End of for -loop to go thorough alphabets
            } // End of for -loop to go thorough states

            // Read number of final states
            numFinalStates = Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[2+numStates*numAlphabets]);
            //System.out.println(numFinalStates);
            // Read final states
            int z=0;
            finalStates = new boolean[numStates];
            int start = 3+numStates*numAlphabets ;
            int end = (3+(numStates*numAlphabets))+numFinalStates;

            for (int fs=start;fs<end;fs++){
                finalStates[ Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[fs])] = true;
                //System.out.println(finalStates[z]);
                z++;
            } // End of for -loop to read all final states

            dfamin x = new dfamin(numStates,numAlphabets,numFinalStates,finalStates,transitionTable);
            //x.minimizer();
            //System.out.println(x);
            //System.out.println("======================");
            int [][] ttt = {{1,2},{0,2},{1,0},{1,2}};
            x.unreachableStates(4,2,ttt);
        } // End of while-loop to read file

        // Close the stream
        br.close();
    }

    dfamin(int nS,int nA,int nFS,boolean fS[], int [][] tT){
        numStates = nS;
        numAlphabets = nA;
        numFinalStates = nFS;
        //alphabets = a;
        finalStates = fS;
        transitionTable = tT;

    } // End of DFAMinimizer constructor

    /*
     * A method to minmize the dfa  
     */
    public void minimizer(){

    } // End of minimizer method

    /*
     * A method to find unreachable states
     * 
     */
    public void unreachableStates(int numStates, int numAlphabets, int [][] transitionTable){
        // Initialize a list to hold temporary list of states in it
        ArrayList<Integer> reachableStates =new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Integer> newStates = new ArrayList();

        // Start from the state zero
        reachableStates.add(0);
        newStates.add(0);
        // Temporary array to hold reachable states
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList();
        // Loop until there is data in newStates
        do {
            // Empty temp array
            temp.clear();
            for (int j=0;j<newStates.size();j++){   
                for (int i=0; i<numAlphabets;i++){
                    //System.out.printf("Alphabets:%d State:%ds ",i,j);
                    //System.out.printf("State:%d newStates:%d \n",j, newStates.get(j));
                    //System.out.printf("transitionTable: %d\n",transitionTable[j][i]);
                    temp.add(transitionTable[j][i]);
                    //System.out.printf("Temp[%d] = %d",i,temp.get(i));
                    //System.out.printf("Alphabets: %d", i);
                } // End of for -loop to go thorough all characters

                //System.out.printf("newStates: %d\n",newStates.get(j));
            } // End of for -loop to go thorough all elements of the newStates array list


            //System.out.printf("newStateSize: %d",newStates.size());
            // Clear newStates list
            newStates.clear();

            //System.out.printf("Temp Size: %d", temp.size());

            // Add the elements that are in temp, but are not in reachableStates to newStates
            for (int z=0;z<temp.size();z++){
                for (int z1=0; z1<reachableStates.size();z1++){
                    // if  the state was already present, don't add
                    if (temp.get(z) == reachableStates.get(z1)){
                        break;
                    }
                    if (temp.get(z) != reachableStates.get(z1) && z1 == reachableStates.size()-1){
                        //System.out.printf("Temp:%d reachableStates:%d z:%d z1:%d \n",temp.get(z),reachableStates.get(z1),z,z1);
                        newStates.add(temp.get(z));
                    }

                    //System.out.printf("ReachableStates: %d ", reachableStates.get(z1));
                } // End of for -loop to go thorough all reachableStates elements and check if  a match
            } // End of for -loop thorugh all temp states
            //System.out.printf("NewStates Size after loop:%d \n",newStates.size());

            if (!newStates.isEmpty()){
                // Add the newStates elements to reachable states
                for (int y=0;y<newStates.size();y++){
                    //System.out.printf("newStates:%d newStatesSize:%d in %d",newStates.get(y),newStates.size(),y);
                    reachableStates.add(newStates.get(y));
                }
            }
            /*
            //System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("reachable states:");
            for (int y=0;y<reachableStates.size();y++){
                System.out.printf("%d",reachableStates.get(y));
            }
            System.out.printf("End!\n");
            */
        } while(!newStates.isEmpty());

        System.out.printf("Reachable sadfStates: ");
        for (int w = 0;w<reachableStates.size()-1;w++){
            System.out.printf(" %d ",reachableStates.get(w));
        }
        System.out.println();
    } // End of unreachableStates method
}
```

Comment: this is too much code with too much cruft left in to be useful as a question. Clean it up, and also note that you're firstly and foremost responsible for finding out where things go wrong: make sure all the algorithm steps are separate methods, and test them to see if they do what they should do on their own. Does that work? test them to see what they do when they run in sequence, etc. Then, if you still can't figure it out, this is the place to ask about it, with all information on what you already tried and didn't help you fix things.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I actually tried to debug it, (that's why there are so many comments in the code), but couldn't figure it out. But i will do it again,

Comment: focus on not having the rest of the code, first. Make that `unreachableStates` method runabble on its own with some hardcoded input, and then step through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an hour of debugging, got it working. I just had to change the problem that I mentioned in DEBUG I (in question). I changed it as following:

```
transitionTable[newStates.get(j)][i]
```